# Do I need to do revision on my accepted paper?

Tags: publications, research-process, publishers

I just received an email of my paper which was submitted to a conference.
The paper submission webpage has the following type of status:

> active (under review),  discuss,  withdrawn,  rejected,  minor
>   revision,  major revision,  accepted,  no show,  published

The status of my paper shows "accepted". However, the reviewer of my papers have pointed out some shortcomings of my paper. (Personally, I think what the comments meant is that it would be nice to have things include in my paper). So the question is, do I need to make that adjustment for the "camera-ready" version? Is it true that only if the status says "minor revision" then you will have to adjust according to the reviewer's comment?

Answer (score 17):

I would interpret "accepted" as "accepted in its current form", i.e. you do not have to make any changes.  But in order to be sure, ask the editor or program committee.

If you *want* to make changes based on the reviewer's comments, that is most likely possible; but again, you should ask the editor to make sure it is okay, and to find out when those changes would be due.

Comment: It is not the camera-ready version, yet. If I want to change one of the graphic, do I still need to inform them?

Comment: @user3222184: I don't know.  Ask the editor / PC.

Answer (score 8):

If it is accepted, then it is to be presented and subsequently published, regardless of whether you make the changes or not. Accepted pending changes (i.e. minor revision or major revision) means that you have to perform the requested changes before the paper may be accepted.

Generally, reviewer comments are there to strengthen the paper's quality, your research, or both.
If you ignore the comments because they don't make sense or simply because you decide not to put the effort, then at least be prepared to justify your choice come time for you to present your work at the conf.

Tldr: You are not obliged to make any changes once it's accepted. Accepted = it'll be presented. It's better that you do the changes.

Comment: it is not the camera ready version yet, if I want to change 1 of the graphics, am I allowed to do that?

Comment: As HBSKan says, it is accepted and will be published regardless of what, if any, changes you make. Note that conferences often have just "accepted/rejected" statuses, because they don't have a second round of checking. So even if "major revisions" are advised, it won't be checked again before publication.

In general, you should include any modifications/suggestions from the reviewer that you feel make sense and improve the quality of your paper.

You can change graphics also, as long as it doesn't change the actual content (i.e. improving clarity is good, demonstrating new results is not).

Comment: @user3222184 Yes, you're normally allowed to change graphics. However, as lifesayko says, don't end up generating a wholly different paper, the one you submitted is the one that was accepted. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

If the reviewers have suggested revisions, you should try to incorporate the suggested changes as far as possible, unless you strongly disagree with some of the comments. Reviewer comments are meant to improve the quality of your paper, and making the changes will ensure that you present an improved version of your paper to your readers.

Regarding the new graphic that you wish to add, I would suggest that you ask the Editor if you can do so.

Answer (score 3):

I would make the corrections if the criticisms are valid.  Regardless of where it is published, you want your work to speak for itself.

Answer (score 2):

Conferences usually do not have a "revision" process, where the reviewers could demand changes prior to publication.

They either reject, or accept.

Nevertheless, they may make some suggestions that could improve your paper a lot. So unless the suggested changes would require major reworking, I suggest to consider them.

Better spend a few hours now to make your paper better, than to regret later. In a few years, you may wish to had mad some of these changes. A better paper gets more attention and citations; even better spelling and presentarion can pay off. **In particular if a reviewer makes some suggestions on what is confusing, it may also confuse other readers in the future.** So improve the explanations, too.